# Django Ajax Form Error - TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a newsletter signup form that sends data to AgileCRM.com and creates a new contact.  The form partly works; it creates the new contact in Agile, but doesn't send the `EmailMessage` notification and I get the `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'` error in console.  There are more than a few SO posts on the subject, but I have no idea how to apply the fix to my situation.

**Ajax**

```
let fields = {
            first_name: 'null',
            last_name: 'null',
            phone_number: 'null',
            email_address: 'null',
        };

        // Footer Form
        $('#footerFormBTN').click(function (e) {
            console.log("create post is working!");
            e.preventDefault();
            fields.first_name = $('#id_first_name').val();
            fields.last_name = $('#id_last_name').val();
            fields.phone_number = $('#id_phone_number').val();
            fields.email_address = $('#id_email_address').val();
            $('#loader').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $('#footerForm').attr('action'),
                data: {
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken'),
                    first_name: fields.first_name,
                    last_name: fields.last_name,
                    phone_number: fields.phone_number,
                    email_address: fields.email_address,
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#id_first_name, #id_last_name, #id_phone_number, #id_email_address').val('');
                    $('#loader').hide();
                    $("#order_message").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close">×</button>Thank you for joining.</div>');
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }, 3000);
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#id_first_name, #id_last_name, #id_phone_number, #id_email_address').val('');
                    $('#loader').hide();
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

**View**

```
def footer_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FooterForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name', '')
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name', '')
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number', '')
            email_address = form.cleaned_data.get('email_address', '')
            subject = 'New Mailing List Subscriber'
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
            # admin_email = ['charles@studiorooster.com']
            recipient_list = ['charles@studiorooster.com', 'omar@****.com', 'info@****.com']
            ctx = {
                'subject': subject,
                'first_name': first_name,
                'last_name': last_name,
                'phone_number': phone_number,
                'email_address': email_address
            }

            agilecrm.create_contact(
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
                email=email_address,
                company='',
                custom={
                    'WebForm': 'Footer Signup'
                },
            )

            message = get_template('email_forms/footer_form_email.html').render(Context(ctx))
            msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email=from_email, to=recipient_list)
            msg.content_subtype = 'html'
            msg.send()

        if form.errors:
            json_data = json.dumps(form.errors)
            return HttpResponseBadRequest(json_data, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404

    return HttpResponse(footer_form)
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rooster/Documents/Development/mylittlecarnival/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/rooster/Documents/Development/mylittlecarnival/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/rooster/Documents/Development/mylittlecarnival/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/rooster/Documents/Development/mylittlecarnival/home/views.py", line 42, in footer_form
    'WebForm': 'Footer Signup'
  File "/Users/rooster/Documents/Development/mylittlecarnival/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/agilecrm/__init__.py", line 99, in create_contact
    result = json.loads(contact.content)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
[01/Mar/2017 08:26:25] "POST /footer_form/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18849
```

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the py-agilecrm library - possibly it's not compatible with Python 3. (That code should probably be accesing `contact.json()` anyway, rather than using `json.loads(contact.content)` - fancy doing a PR?)

Comment: `contact.json()` did the trick.  I would love to do a PR - I will add to my todo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That means you pass some `bytes` arguments (`first_name, last_name, email_address`) to `agilecrm.create_contact`.
Simple to find it by `print`,solve it by `arg.decode('ENCODING_TYPE(eg: utf-8)')`.